# What does the following runtime error mean: "terminate called without an active exception\n Aborted"

Tags: c++, try-catch

The bug disturbed me about two days: when running the code I have a runtime error of "terminate called without an active exception\n Aborted",why?

I try to locate the code and find the line may be exit the code "xx = new int [num]", the    num in my test case is about 640000(64MB memory to new). when I set the num much smaller as 10, it is OK, but my code get a wrong answer this time.

I try to delete all the "try/catch" Clause but still have this error.

Also I // all the function which call the "xx = new int [num]" clause, the error still exist, and this time I locate the code may exit is a normal "for loop".

All the case passed the compiler, have u ever met this error in running your code?Thank you!

I // some delete clause and get the error below:
*** glibc detected *** ./ESMF_RegridWeightGen: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000005cd376 ***

Comment: Try putting a `try/catch` block around your entire `main` body and see if there are any exceptions at all...

Comment: Do you have a small code sample that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: do you have multiple threads?

Comment: http://chillyc.info/?s=terminate+called+without+an+active+exception see this... is about empty throw. eg: throw;

Answer (score 19):

When I've seen this error, it was caused by the thread object destructing before the thread it encapsulated has exited.

Comment: It might have nothing to do with the thread at all. You might have `std::thread foo(...)` in a local block, and throw an exception after you start the thread. Before your exception is caught, the thread destructor happens, and it calls `std::terminate()`, which makes it hard to debug the real exception!

Answer (score 7):

I encountered this when I tried to use throw; outside of a catch clause. The rethrow fails and that error message is displayed.

Answer (score 4):

The "terminate without an active exception" message is a hint that, at some point in your program, exception handling got broken.

The memory allocation is probably the primary cause, but probably not the error site. The large allocation will throw a std::bad_alloc exception, and this exception is incorrectly handled somewhere.

To validate the theory, insert a line like

```
 throw std::logic_error("Foo");
```

above the allocation, this should trigger the bug as well.

I've encountered two common causes for this:

- Multithreaded mingw programs compiled without the right flags
- A destructor that was called as part of the stack unwinding process has thrown an exception

You should be able to diagnose the latter condition with a debugger. A stack trace of your application (e.g. obtained by running it in gdb) should help greatly.

Comment: what about ~2.5GB  allocation? 640000*sizeof(int)

Comment: @neagoegab: Last time I checked, sizeof(int) < 10, so 640,000 * sizeof(int) < 6,400,000 < 6,4 MB. It might be too large and might throw a std::bad_alloc. Which should result, at worst, in a terminate call that prints std::bad_alloc, not in "terminate called without an active exception". There is a worse problem somewhere, and his too large allocation is just triggering it.

Answer (score 2):

Like Gearoid Murphy said the error happens when the thread object is destructed before the thread function itself has been fully executed. I detected this error using tinythread library (http://tinythreadpp.bitsnbites.eu/):

Before:

```
#include "tinythread.h"
...
void fork_thread(void (*function_pointer)(void * arg), void * arg_pointer) {
    tthread::thread t(function_pointer, arg_pointer);
    // t is destructed here, causing the "terminate called ..." error
}
```

After:

```
#include "tinythread.h"
...
void fork_thread(void (*function_pointer)(void * arg), void * arg_pointer) {
    tthread::thread * t = new tthread::thread(function_pointer, arg_pointer);
    // now the new thread object is not destructed here, preventing
    // the "terminate called ..." error. Remember that because thread
    // object must now be destructed explicitly (i.e. manually) with delete
    // call you should store the pointer t to a vector of thread pointers
    // for example.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With MinGW, adding the `-mthreads` compiler option to gcc solves this problem.

From [the gcc manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2.3/gcc/i386-and-x86-64-Options.html):

> > -mthreads
> >
> > Support thread-safe exception handling on Mingw32. Code that relies on thread-safe exception handling must compile and link all code with the -mthreads option. When compiling, -mthreads defines -D_MT; when linking, it links in a special thread helper library -lmingwthrd which cleans up per thread exception handling data.