# How do I verify if runtime failure is due to too many threads spawned?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am using `std::thread` and gcc as my compiler in implementing the parallel-merge as described in [Cormen's Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844).

I think I got the code to work.  It passes all randomly seeded arrays that are not too big.  However, when I try to merge two arrays that are large (1e6 elements each), I get the following termination:

```
terminate called without an active exception
terminate called recursively
terminate called recursively
```

Using gdb doesn't help: it becomes corrupted during the run.

I am pretty certain that the run has failed due to too many threads spawned.

*What can I do to confirm that this error is due to too many std::threads spawned?*

**NOTES**

1. Code works up to n=1e4, fails by n=1e5
2. ## define DEBUG if you want to see output, but I don't recommend this except for small n like 10 or 50.
3. STRBUF_SIZE/use of fprintf is ugly, but iostream doesn't flush well in threads - this is hacky, but works (no need to focus here).
4. I tried following Barnes53's suggestion by using a try/catch block around the threads, but this didn't work, apparently.
5. I know that spawning a gazillion threads is a bad thing - at this point, I am just trying to implement what's in the book and to see if it works, and perhaps discover what its limitations are.

**UPDATE**

1. [GManNickG's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14409088/975129) helped: not every run, but during some runs of 1e5, I can see that, indeed, resources are gone.
2. I will probably look into some kind of k-way parallel sort, where I can control the number of threads spawned, if this algorithm is not salvageable.

**CODE**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>

#define STRBUF_SIZE 1024

class Random
{
public:
    Random( unsigned int seed=::time(nullptr))
        : m_seed( seed )
    { }
    // between [ 0 .. n-1 ]
    unsigned int rand_uint( unsigned int n )
    {
        return static_cast<unsigned int>
                     (static_cast<float>(n) * rand_r( &m_seed ) / RAND_MAX);
    }
    unsigned int getSeed() const { return m_seed; }
private:
    unsigned int m_seed;
};

template<typename T>
char* dump( char* line, T it1, T it2 )
{
    char buf[80];
    line[0] = '\0';
    for( T it=it1; it!=it2; ++it )
    {
        sprintf( buf, "%u ", *it );
        strcat(  line, buf );
    }
    return line;
}

template< typename T, class It >
It binary_search_it( It beg, It end, const T& value )
{
    auto low  = beg;
    auto high = std::max( beg, end );   // end+1
    while( low < high )
    {
        auto mid = low + std::distance( low, high ) / 2;
        if ( value <= *mid )
            high = mid;
        else
            low = mid + 1;
    }
    return high;
}

template< class InputIt, class OutputIt >
void p_merge( 
    char const*  msg, 
    unsigned     depth,
    unsigned     parent_lvl_id,
    unsigned     lr,
    InputIt  p1, InputIt  r1, 
    InputIt  p2, InputIt  r2, 
    OutputIt p3, OutputIt r3
    )
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    char buff[STRBUF_SIZE];
#endif
    unsigned sum_prev  = pow( 2, depth ) - 1;
    unsigned lvl_id    = 2*parent_lvl_id + lr;
    unsigned thread_no = sum_prev + lvl_id + 1;

    unsigned limit0    = sum_prev + 1;
    unsigned limit1    = pow( 2, depth+1 ) - 1;

#ifdef DEBUG
    char msg_dep[256];
    sprintf( msg_dep, "%s [%2d] %-10d [%d,%d]", msg, depth, thread_no, limit0, limit1 );
    fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", msg_dep );
#endif

    if ( thread_no<limit0 || thread_no>limit1 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "OUT OF BOUNDS\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    auto n1 = std::distance( p1, r1 );
    auto n2 = std::distance( p2, r2 );
#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf( stderr, "%s dist[v1]=%2ld   : %s\n", msg_dep, n1, dump( buff, p1, r1 ) );
    fprintf( stderr, "%s dist[v2]=%2ld   : %s\n", msg_dep, n2, dump( buff, p2, r2 ) );
#endif
    if ( n1<n2 )
    {
        std::swap( p1, p2 );
        std::swap( r1, r2 );
        std::swap( n1, n2 );
#ifdef DEBUG
      fprintf( stderr, "%s swapped[v1]   : %s\n", msg_dep, dump( buff, p1, r1 ));
      fprintf( stderr, "%s swapped[v2]   : %s\n", msg_dep, dump( buff, p2, r2 ));
#endif
    }
    if ( n1==0 )
    {
#ifdef DEBUG
      fprintf( stderr, "%s done              \n", msg_dep );
#endif
        return;
    }
    auto q1 = p1 + n1 / 2;   // midpoint
    auto q2 = binary_search_it( p2, r2, *q1 );  // <q1   q2[q1]   >=q1
    auto q3 = p3 + std::distance( p1, q1 ) + std::distance( p2, q2 );
    *q3 = *q1;

#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf( stderr, "%s q1[median]=%u  : %s\n", msg_dep, *q1, dump( buff, p1, r1 ));
    fprintf( stderr, "%s q2[fulcrum]=%u : %s\n", msg_dep, *q2, dump( buff, p2, r2 ));
    fprintf( stderr, "%s q3(copied)=%u  : %s\n", msg_dep, *q3, dump( buff, p3, r3 ));
#endif

#ifdef DEBUG
    auto d1 = std::distance( p1,   q1-1 );
    auto d2 = std::distance( q1+1, r1   );
    fprintf( stderr, "%s q1[dist_L]=%ld  : %s\n", msg_dep, d1, dump( buff, p1, r1 ));
    fprintf( stderr, "%s q1[dist_M]=%ld  : %s\n", msg_dep, d2, dump( buff, p1, r1 ));
#endif


    try {
        std::thread t1{ 
            [&](){ p_merge( "LESS", depth+1, lvl_id, 0, p1, q1,   p2, q2,   p3, r3 ); } 
        };
        std::thread t2{ 
            [&](){ p_merge( "MORE", depth+1, lvl_id, 1, q1+1, r1, q2, r2, q3+1, r3 ); } 
        };
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "OK - I am dying during a std::thread spawn\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf( stderr, "%s synchronized\n", msg_dep );
#endif
}

int
main( int argv, char* argc[] )
{
    // ok up to 1e4, fails by 1e5
    unsigned n = 1e5; 
    Random   r;
    std::vector<unsigned> v1( n ), v2( n ), v3( 2 * n );

#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf( stderr, "SEED = %u\n", r.getSeed() );
#endif

    std::generate( v1.begin(), v1.end(), [&]() { return r.rand_uint(n); } );
    std::generate( v2.begin(), v2.end(), [&]() { return r.rand_uint(n); } );

#ifdef DEBUG
    char buff[STRBUF_SIZE];
    fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", dump( buff, v1.begin(), v1.end() ));
    fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", dump( buff, v2.begin(), v2.end() ));
#endif

    std::sort( v1.begin(), v1.end() );
    std::sort( v2.begin(), v2.end() );

    p_merge( "TOP ", 0, 0, 0,
        v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), v3.begin(), v3.end() );

    assert( std::is_sorted( v3.begin(), v3.end() ));

#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf( stderr, "FINAL : %s\n", dump( buff, v3.begin(), v3.end() ));
#endif
}
```

Comment: Have you tried breaking on `pthread_create`? Anyway - my guess would be that it is some memory corruption and try run under valgrind.

Comment: If `std::thread` can't spawn a thread it should throw a `system_error` exception that indicates that.

Comment: Exactly how many threads do you create? I would expect a modern system to be able to create several hundred threads without failing in itself. Is this on Linux or Windows?

Comment: @bames53 +1 - going to try that out right now - will report back

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105028/why-return-me-this-error-terminate-called-without-an-active-exception-n-aborted

Comment: @MatsPetersson the algorithm recursively spawns threads so I think it may be generating way too many (problem may be due to academics creating an algorithm that works well, in theory) - this is on Linux

Comment: you really should fix the real problem, creating too many threads is going to make your code slower...

Comment: So, put a counter to see how many threads you are actually creating - but creating (many) more threads than there are processor cores on your system isn't going to be any benefit at all, so unless you have a massive machine with hundreds or thousands of processor cores, I would expect you wouldn't run out of threads!

Comment: @KarolyHorvath at this point, I'm just trying to verify that the problem is, indeed due to too many threads.  Unfortunately, if that is the case, the algorithm may not be salvageable - I will have to have a look when I reach that juncture.

Comment: My system (Fedora Core 16, x86-64, linux 3.7.0-rc5+ kernel, 16GB RAM) is able to create a little more than 800 threads. But it definitely throws the std::system_error when it can't create more threads. I suspect your code is going wrong elsewhere. My suggestion to count the number of threads was more to indicate whether you are reaching that limit or not - if your code reaches, say, 50 threads, then we can be pretty sure that it's not "number of threads" that is the problem.

Comment: @MatsPetersson if you check here:  http://www.catonmat.net/blog/mit-introduction-to-algorithms-part-thirteen/ near the bottom, it describes the p-merge-sort algorithm.  It is virtually spawning a "binary tree" full for threads - this explains why the code runs fine for small n, but not for large.  I am going to focus on combining a plain iterative merge sort with this p-merge.  I plan to only allow it to spawn 8 threads before calling the iterative version.

Comment: Ok, so log2(1e6) is around 20, so definitely need a lot bigger arrays to reach 800... Although your new method is probably more efficient, I doubt running out of threads is actually your problem.

Comment: Some people write code in terms of logical and physical threads.    They write their code nice and clean using logical threads, but then have a layer to map and multiplex logical to physical threads.  std::thread is a physical thread.

Comment: Don't use a thread per merge.  Use a pool of [num of cores] threads, (or some sensible, samll number that will ensure all cores get used on current platforms, eg. 32).  Recursively submit merge-tasks until  a sumbitted task finds its partition is less than [L1 cache size], then in-place sort with quicksort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can catch `std::system_error` and check if the code is `resource_unavailable_try_again`:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <system_error>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

class thread_collection
{
public:
    thread_collection() :
    mStop(false)
    {}

    ~thread_collection()
    {
        clear();
    }

    template <typename Func, typename... Args>
    bool add(Func&& func, Args&&... args)
    {
        try
        {
            mThreads.emplace_back(std::forward<Func>(func),
                                  std::cref(mStop),
                                  std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
        catch (const std::system_error& e)
        {
            if (e.code().value() == std::errc::resource_unavailable_try_again)
                return false; // not possible to make more threads right now
            else
                throw; // something else
        }

        return true; // can keep going
    }

    void clear()
    {
        mStop = true;
        for (auto& thread : mThreads)
        {
            if (thread.joinable())
                thread.join();
        }

        mThreads.clear();
        mStop = true;
    }

    std::size_t size() const
    {
        return mThreads.size();
    }

private:
    thread_collection(const thread_collection&);
    thread_collection& operator=(const thread_collection&);

    std::atomic<bool> mStop;
    std::vector<std::thread> mThreads;
};

void worker(const std::atomic<bool>& stop)
{
    while (!stop)
        std::this_thread::yield();
}

int main()
{
    thread_collection threads;

    try
    {
        while (threads.add(worker))
            continue;

        std::cout << "Exhausted thread resources!" << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Stopped for some other reason: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Made: " << threads.size() << " threads." << std::endl;
    threads.clear();
}
```

*(Run this at your own risk!)*

According §30.3.1.2/4, this is the error code used to indicate thread creation failure:

> Error conditions:
>   resource_unavailable_try_again — the system lacked the necessary resources to create another thread, or the system-imposed limit on the number of threads in a process would be exceeded.

Note this could be thrown by your own arguments being copied to the resulting thread. To guarantee against this, you need to pre-construct your arguments, then no-throw move them to your thread function.

That said, you're much better off putting a limit on thread creation anyway. There's no point in having more threads running than cores can execute. Use `std::thread::hardware_concurrency` to get that number.

Comment: +1 great post (very informative/useful) - ty: I will try this out

Comment: When you rethrow the `system_error` it will destroy the vector `threads` which will call `~thread` and that will call `terminate()` because the threads are joinable. I know this is only an example but is unsafe and it could be used by people who don't know better. You should put the loop that joins the threads in a scopeguard-type object to be exception safe.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: True, how's that?

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
    std::thread t1{ 
        [&](){ p_merge( "LESS", depth+1, lvl_id, 0, p1, q1,   p2, q2,   p3, r3 ); } 
    };
    std::thread t2{ 
        [&](){ p_merge( "MORE", depth+1, lvl_id, 1, q1+1, r1, q2, r2, q3+1, r3 ); } 
    };
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
catch( ... )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "OK - I am dying during a std::thread spawn\n" );
    exit( 1 );
}
```

This code may not do what you expect.  If constructing `t2` throws an exception then `t1` will be destroyed but because that thread is joinable it will call `std::terminate()` so your `catch` will not handle the exception.

One reason you're seeing `terminate called recursively` could be that lots of threads have that same problem at once, so lots of threads call `terminate()` at similar times.

This would work instead:

```
std::thread t1;
std::thread t2;

try {
    t1 = std::thread{ 
        [&](){ p_merge( "LESS", depth+1, lvl_id, 0, p1, q1,   p2, q2,   p3, r3 ); } 
    };
    t2 = std::thread{ 
        [&](){ p_merge( "MORE", depth+1, lvl_id, 1, q1+1, r1, q2, r2, q3+1, r3 ); } 
    };
}
catch( ... )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "OK - I am dying during a std::thread spawn\n" );
    exit( 1 );
}

t1.join();
t2.join();
```

I don't think it's a problem here because the only place in `p_merge` that can throw is inside a `try` block, but you should also be aware that if an exception leaves the function run by `std::thread` that will also call `std::terminate()` so it that's not what you want then you should pass `noexcept` functions (or just non-throwing functions) to `std::thread`.